# How to retrieve pre-set value from list call

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

```
list_1=[one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]

list_a=[list_1[0],list_1[1],list_1[2]]

list_b=[list_1[3],list_1[4],list_1[5]]

list_c=[list_1[6],list_1[7],list_1[8]]
```

What do I do if I want to find what value of x `list_(a,b,c...ect)[list_1[x]]`

for what I am using this to do, assume all the values in `list_1` can be the same value or different values than each other

ex. `list_1=[one,one,one,two,one,six,seven,three,one]`

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do - maybe show some small data and expected result. BTW: `list_a = list_1[0:3]` `list_b = list_1[3:6]`, `list_c = list_1[6:9]`

Comment: BTW: maybe you should keep it in dictionary to use strings "a", "b", etc. to access elements - `data["a"] = list_1[0:3]`

Comment: to get value from `list_a` you can use `list_a[0]` or `list_a[x]` but after converting to `list_a`, `list_b`, etc. all of them have only indexes `0,1,2` and they don't remeber what was original position in `list_1` - you have to manually convert `x` to name of list and index in list - but it would be easier if you would use dictionary `dict[0] = list_1[0:3]` or nested list `data = [ list_1[0:3], list_1[3:6], list_1[6:9] ]` and then you can use `data[p][q]` where `3*p+q = x`